# Need a batchfile to run on startup/shutdown, logon/logoff & lock/unlock for a Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not yet a programmer but looking for a solution that is not made yet seems fun. I do have some questions about the solution I look for.

**Situation**: I have a keyboard that needs an application to make customization possible. But this software makes the keyboard go crazy every time I logoff, lock, shutdown or reboot the PC. I did notice that when I force close the application, the keyboard's customization stays the way I configured it.

So, I made a small batchfile that force close this application:

```
taskkill /im Lcore.exe /f
```

Really small, I know, but it does what it has to do, force closing LogitechGamingSoftware.exe

**Problem**: This batchfile should run every time the application would be closed by Windows itself.
Using the Task scheduler doesn't seem to work. And making it work trough gpedit.msc also fails.

**Question**: What do I do wrong to get this small file to to what I want it to do at the right moment?

In task scheduler I tried it this way:

1. Make a new task
2. Name it, execute only if user is logged on, with elevated privileges
3. Trigger: @ locking of the workstation, any user
4. Action: execute application, `c:\Scripts\Batch\ForceCloseLGS.bat`
5. Conditions: stock settings
6. settings: Task might be executed on request, task execute as fast as possible

Save and test.

Doesn't do anything at all.
If pressed Win+L keys, keyboard goes haywire.
But if I execute the batch from the task scheduler menu, it works.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close because it's borderline enough that it sort of fits here, but I think you'd get better answers on SuperUser.

Comment: Can I or someone move my question to SuperUser?

Comment: I flagged it for you. In the future, click the "flag" link below your question, choose "In need of moderator attention" and just explain what you'd like done.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want that program to startup look in regedit (Win + R, type in regedit press enter) but you may want to avoid this because if you edit registry YOUR COMPUTER COULD BE GONE (you'll have to reinstall Windows). Soooooo... Yeah. Oh and btw the reg key might be in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run or (Something to do with users sorry don't know it of the top of my head.) \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run then look for the exe but if you want a program (or Batch File) to run on startup add a string thingy to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE one above with the value as the path to your program (again, or a batch file. Eg. "C:\My Scripts\Startup Script.bat". I hope this helps you!

Comment: You are right but the software needs to run.
The software stores lighting profiles and macrokeys. If the software doesn't run at all, the lighting would be and stays just perfect.
But then I don't have the custom lighting or any macrokey at all.

I thought of don't autostart the software at all. And fired it up only when "in need" of a custom lighting or macrokeys. Let's say, only when I play games or the daughter is learning to type.